# Default Values AND Remove matching suffix

Tags: bash

Is there a way to do the [default values `${foo:-bar}`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and the [remove matching suffix `${foo%bar}`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) bash feature in the same time ?

Something like that: `${foo%suffix:-default}`

In other words, I want:

- If `foo` is unset or null use the `default` value
- If `foo` is set remove any `suffix` at the end

Comment: Don't think it can be done without creating a shell variable.

Comment: Ok thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Something like that: `${foo%suffix:-default}`

It's not possible to achieve what you want in a manner similar to what you've described.

However, you could use *control operators* to achieve the desired result without making use of temporary variables:

```
$ FOO=foobar
$ [ -z "$FOO" ] && FOO=default || FOO=${FOO%bar}
$ echo $FOO
foo
$ FOO=
$ [ -z "$FOO" ] && FOO=default || FOO=${FOO%bar}
$ echo $FOO
default
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use default *assignment* instead of default *substitution*. This is also a use for the `:` "no-op" command:

```
: ${foo:=default}
echo ${foo%suffix}
```

testing:

```
$ default=foobar suffix=bar
$ foo=hello  ; : ${foo:=$default}; echo $foo ${foo%$suffix}
hello hello
$ foo=ironbar; : ${foo:=$default}; echo $foo ${foo%$suffix}
ironbar iron
$ unset foo  ; : ${foo:=$default}; echo $foo ${foo%$suffix}
foobar foo
```